# Keyboard behavior in the modal react nartive

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

react native modal android , keyboard pushing the whole modal, how to make sure keyboard is only pushing the content of the modal. on iOS it is not pushing the modal , but the covering the content . It should push the content up.

```
    <Modal
      isVisible={true}
      style={{
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        margin: 0,
      }}
     
      backdropOpacity={0.5}
      animationIn="slideInUp" bottom
      animationOut="slideOutDown" close
    >
      {/* <KeyboardAvoidingView
  behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
  style={{flex:1}}> */}

      <View style={{height: 500, gap: 16, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
      <TextInput style={{borderWidth: 1}}></TextInput>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
        <Text>aasasas</Text>
      </View>
    </Modal>
```

here for iOS keyboard is covering the content and for android the modal is pushed up, what I want is only the content to be pushed and scrollable. The content can scroll behind the keyboard
[image: iOS]
[image: ios]

Comment: Can you post the modal code and and a screenshot.

Comment: @MichaelBahl done

Answer (score 0):

I have created an [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/modal-keybboard-obscure)

Just move the `KeyboardAvoidingView` within the `Modal`

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import {
  TextInput,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Button,
  View,
  Modal,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

export default CustomModal = () => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title={'Open Modal'} onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)} />
      {modalVisible && (
        <Modal animationType="slide" transparent={true} visible={modalVisible}>
          <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={'padding'}>
            <View style={styles.modalContentContainer}>
              <Button
                title={'Close Modal'}
                onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}
              />
              <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
                <TextInput
                  value={'test 1'}
                  onChangeText={() => {}}
                  onBlur={() => {}}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
                <TextInput
                  value={'test 2'}
                  onChangeText={() => {}}
                  onBlur={() => {}}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
                <TextInput
                  value={'test 3'}
                  onChangeText={() => {}}
                  onBlur={() => {}}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
                <TextInput
                  value={'test 4'}
                  onChangeText={() => {}}
                  onBlur={() => {}}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </Modal>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textInputContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center'
  },
  modalContentContainer: {
    height: '100%',
  },
});
```

Comment: No this is what what I want , keyboard is pushing the modal up, it should not push the modal up. Its should just overlay over the content and content should be scrollable

Comment: @Lelouch I have updated my example

Comment: hello @Michael Thank you for the update. This is pretty close to the solution, but on  thing is bothering me The keyboard on iOS is pushing the content out of the screen. Also the modal is opening to the full height maybe it should be around 0.8 times the screen height. I tried adding max height in your code but it was leaving some big gap below the content. Could you please check this out